# How to add post into a category programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm new to Wordpress and php,so sorry for my basic question.
I want to add some posts in a category programmatically.
For example every day i want to select some posts and insert them into a category with php code and for next day replace some other posts.
Is it possible? How?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `wp_insert_post` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

See the Codex, here you have a lot of examples:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

To update the Post see `wp_update_post` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: I don't want to insert new post to database. i just want to add posts that exist in database to category programmatically.

Comment: Read? The last 2 lines give you an answer!

Answer (score 10):

Use [wp_set_post_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/)

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array( 1, 2 ) );
```

Comment: If i set new category for my post, can i return it to previous category? for example i want, when a user visit my site, put some posts in a category and when user leave my site, posts return to previous category.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Because i'm using [Post Rating](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-ratings/) plugin for scoring posts and also my theme should get a category for showing on slider. and i want to show most rating posts on slider. what should i do? :(